# Send QRcode to email using java

Tags: java

Can I send QRcode to email directly without any local storage work using java?The code below generates QRcode.

```
public static void createQRCode(String qrCodeData, String filePath,
String charset, Map hintMap, int qrCodeheight, int qrCodewidth)
throws WriterException, IOException {
BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(
    new String(qrCodeData.getBytes(charset), charset),
    BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, qrCodewidth, qrCodeheight, hintMap);
MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile(matrix, filePath.substring(filePath
    .lastIndexOf('.') + 1), new File(filePath));
System.out.println("QR code encoded");
}

public static String readQRCode(String filePath, String charset, Map hintMap)
throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NotFoundException {
BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
    new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(
            ImageIO.read(new     FileInputStream(filePath)))));
Result qrCodeResult = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitmap,
    hintMap);
return qrCodeResult.getText();
}
```

I want to attach this above generated QR to this below code in body section without storing it locally. I'm using eclipse Mars.. Please do help me out

```
String from = USER_NAME;
String pass = PASSWORD;
String[] to = {RECIPIENT};
String subject = "Java mail example";
String body= "hi this is tetsting mail!";


Properties props = System.getProperties();
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");


Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

try {


message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

// To get the array of addresses
for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
   toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
}

for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
   message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
}

message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText(body, "UTF-8", "html");

Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host, from, pass);
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
System.out.println("Email Sent successfully");

}
catch (AddressException ae) {
ae.printStackTrace();
}
catch (MessagingException me) {
me.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Check this out: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_inlineimage_in_email.htm

Comment: Should try to save this QR code as an image and then send it as email

Comment: Just use #writeToStream isteed of file https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/client/j2se/MatrixToImageWriter.html#writeToStream-com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix-java.lang.String-java.io.OutputStream-